# Отправить данные с сайта на js сервер GET-запросом

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

имеется сайт:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         <!--
             function httpGet()
             {
                 var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                 xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://192.168.0.12:8080", false );
                 xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("data", "123");
                 xmlHttp.send( null );
                 return xmlHttp.responseText;
             }
         //-->
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <input type="button" onclick="httpGet()" value="Click" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html
```

И сервер:

```
var http = require("http");
var fs =  require("fs");

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    var temp = fs.readFileSync("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp");
    var temp_c = temp/1000;

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Raspberry Pi cpu temperature: ");
    response.write("\n" + temp);
    response.write("\n" + temp_c);
    response.end();
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Необходимо вывести значение заголовка data, но в HTTP.IncomingMessage нет методов для вывода одного заголовка. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers

Comment: Мне надо получить значение только одного заголовка, message.headers выводит все заголовки

Comment: выводит в виде объекта, да? а в нём есть интересующий вас заголовок?